# Not gready regex doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Regex:

```
preg_match('/<td[^<^>]*>(.*?)<\/td><td[^<^>]*>'.preg_quote('<input type=\'text\' name=\'nazwisko\'>', '/').'<\/td>/Ui', $form_string, $matches);
```

Input:

```
<form action='http://freebot.pl/post.php' name='implebot.plSHOW' method='post' onsubmit='return SprawdzFormularz(this)'>
        <table><tr><td align=right>

        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='60431'>
        Email :</td><td><input type='text' name='email'></td></tr>
    <tr><td align=right>Imię :</td><td><input type='text' name='imie'></td></tr><tr><td align=right>Nazwisko :</td><td><input type='text' name='nazwisko'></td></tr><tr><td align=right>#opcja1 :</td><td><input type='text' name='pole_1' value='war.1'></td></tr><input type='hidden' name='pole_2' value='war.2'><tr><td align=right>#opcja3 :</td><td><select name='pole_3'><option></option><option value='s1'>s1</option><option value='s2'>s2</option><option value='s3'>s3</option><option value='s4'>s4</option><option value='s5'>s5</option></select><tr><td align=right>#opcja4 :</td><td><select name='pole_4'><option></option><option value='a'>a</option><option value='b'>b</option><option value='c'>c</option><option value='d'>d</option><option value='e'>e</option><option value='f'>f</option><option value='g'>g</option></select><tr><td align=right>#opcja5 :</td><td><input type='text' name='pole_5' value='war.5'></td></tr></table><input type='hidden' name='zrodlo' value='formularz1'>Zgadzam się z <input type='checkbox' name='pp' checked><a href='http://' >polityką prywatności</a><br><input type='submit' value='Wyślij'></form>
```

$matches[1]:

```
<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='60431'>Email :</td><td><input type='text' name='email'></td></tr><tr><td align=right>Imi─Ö :</td><td><input type='text' name='imie'></td></tr><tr><td align=right>Nazwisko :
```

Instead of:

```
Nazwisko :
```

I got `(.*?)` in `<td[^<^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>` which should give me expected `Nazwisko :`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why `preg_quote()` something that is static (and has no regex meta characters in it)?

Comment: This would be much less painful if you used an HTML parser instead of regex.

Comment: it's static only in this example;) in script is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use ungreedy quantifiers in this pattern. Try this instead:

```
preg_match('~<td[^>]*>([^<]*)</td><td[^>]*>'
          .preg_quote("<input type='text' name='nazwisko'>")
          .'</td>~i', $form_string, $matches);
```

If td tags can contain html content, you can replace `([^<]*)` by `((?>[^<]+|<+(?!/td>))*)`

explanation:

```
(?>             # atomic group
    [^<]+       # all characters expect < one or more times
   |            # OR
    <+(?!/td>)  # < one or more times not followed by /td> (negative lookahead)
)*              # close atomic group, 0 or more times
```

In other words, this part match: all characters that are not < or < not followed by /td>, each 1 or more times, all of this 0 or more times.
It's a little longer than `(.*?)` but it is more efficient as far.

The reason is that the regex engine must test that each character, one by one, is followed by `</td>` for the  ungreedy pattern.
In my pattern the regex engine test only when the character is `<`.

I use an atomic group `(?>...)` instead a non capturing group `(?:...)` when it is possible, as a good practice, you can find more infos [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

Comment: Previous td can contain label wrapped by <span> or some hidden inputs, etc.

Comment: Can you add explanation? I know ?> is back lookaround and ?! is negation of forward lookaround, but how it work together?

Comment: @MaciejPyszyński: `(?>...)` is an atomic group, `(?<=...)` is a lookbehind. See my edit for more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

`/U` means switching between greedy & ungreedy is reversed: `.*` is ungreedy, `.*?` is greedy.

Comment: Thx, for taking that out, but the result with `'/<td[^<^>]*>(.*?)<\/td><td[^<^>]*>'.preg_quote('<input type=\'text\' name=\'nazwisko\'>', '/').'<\/td>/i'` is still the same. There's something strange with this case and I cannot find what it is...